# margin-top varies depending on the content

Tags: html, css

I would like to have all the buttons have a margin-top to the buttoncontainer of 0 or some other value.
But somehow it seems like this works or not depending on the content. The more the buttons content linebreaks vary the more the margin-top is different.
How to make them all align?

```css
.buttoncontainer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttoncontainer">
  <button></button>
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test test test </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to margin. If you set `vertical-align: middle` for the buttons, they will be properly aligned.

```css
.buttoncontainer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttoncontainer">
  <button></button>
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test test test </button>
</div>
```

Because inline-block elements has [`vertical-align: baseline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) as default. If you don't set it as `middle`, it will be aligned like this.

[image]

```css
.buttoncontainer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
}

button {
  margin-top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* vertical-align: baseline; this is default */
}
```

```html
<div class="buttoncontainer">
  <button>a</button>
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test test test </button>
</div>
```